# Automatically process numbers in e (scientific) notation in python

Tags: python, numbers

I am reading in data files from a mass spectrometer and many of the numbers are in e form e.g.

```
4096.26 5.785e1
4096.29 5.784e1
4096.31 5.784e1
4096.33 5.784e1
4096.36 5.783e1
```

I am planning on using the split function to get the two numbers out, but I wanted to know is there a function to convert the second column into python floats? I know I could do it with regular expressions but thought there might be a better way

Thank you

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `float()` constructor will accept strings in `e` notation:

```
>>> float("5.785e1")
57.85
```

So you can simply use `map(float, line.split())` to convert a text line to a list of floats.

Comment: Best thing I've ever seen with python

Comment: @Joeydanieldarko It [totally will](https://ideone.com/LYxgW3).

Comment: @SvenMarnach it will return `8.7e-07` which isn't a float

Comment: @Joeydanieldarko I'm not sure how you come to this conclusion, but rest assured that the object returned by the `float()` constructor is always a `float`.